# How to set OnClick on Programmatically TableRow?

Tags: android, loops, android-studio

I have programmatically `TableRow`. Then I loop it like this:

```
int countData = dbData.readRows();
for(int i = 0;i<countData;i++) {
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
    TextView tvMessage = new TextView(getActivity());
    tvMessage.setText("Click Here");
    tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    tr.addView(tvMessage);
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get you..